# How to install MySql db package in install4j in silent mode in LINUX.?

Tags: java, mysql, installation, install4j

How to install MySql db package in install4j in silent mode in LINUX?

For installing MySql db I have all the required packages

```
1) MySQL-client-community-5.1.57-1.rhel4.i386.rpm
2) MySQL-devel-community-5.1.57-1.rhel4.i386.rpm
3) MySQL-server-community-5.1.57-1.rhel4.i386.rpm
```

And to install these packages in Linux we have few steps like ::

```
1) rpm -qa | grep -i mysql
2) rpm -e mysql –nodeps
3) rpm -e mysql-server-5.0.22-2.1
4) rpm -ivh MySQL-server-community-5.1.57-1.rhel4.i386.rpm 
5) rpm -ivh MySQL-client-community-5.1.57-1.rhel4.i386.rpm 
6) rpm -ivh MySQL-devel-community-5.1.57-1.rhel4.i386.rpm 
7) /usr/bin/mysqladmin -u root password 'password'
8) mysql -V
9) mysql -u root -p
```

I want all these steps to be taken care by install4j.

How to do all this stuff in install4j?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just add all the RPM files to your distribution tree in install4j. Then it depends if your media file is an installer or just an RPM archive.

- for an installer media file, you add a shell script with the above commands to the distribution tree that you invoke with a "Run executable" action.
- for an RPM media file, you add the above commands to the "post-installation script" that can be configured in the media wizard.